# Indexing data from postgres to solr/elasticsearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, solr

What is the best way to index constantly changing data in a PostgreSQL database to a Solr/Elasticsearch database?

I have a postgres database on AWS RDS and i want to perform complex search on it. However the data i will query against is constantly changing with very high writes/ updates. So i am not sure how i should transfer the data to the solr/ elasticsearch efficiently and reliably.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the risk of someone marking this question as a duplicate, here's the link to setting up [postgres-to-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716272/setting-up-elasticsearch-with-postgresql) in another StackOverflow thread. There's also [this blog post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/02/realtime-requests-psql-elasticsearch/) on Atlassian that also talks about how to get real time updates from PostgreSQL into ElasticSearch.

The Atlassian thread, for the tl;dr crowd, uses stored PGS procedures to copy updated/inserted data to a staging table, then separately processes the staging table. It's a nice approach that would work for either ES or Solr. Unfortunately, it's a roll-your-own solution, unless you are familiar with Clojure.

Answer (score 5):

In case of `Solr`, a general approach is to use `Data Import Handler` (`DIH` for short). Config the full-import & delta-import sql properly, where `delta import` import data from database that changes since last import judging via timestamps (so, u need design schema with proper timestamps).

The **timing of delta-import**, has 2 styles which could be used separately or combined:

- Do delta-import with a timer. (e.g every 5 minutes)
- After each update in database, make a call to delta-import.

Refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler for `DIH` detail.