# Postgres to ElasticSearch Data Replication Real time Solution

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, full-text-search, replication

I am having Spring Boot application with Postgres but for search we want to use elasticsearch but we need to sent postgres data to elasticSearch. Is there production ready best approach can you suggest . solution which we can implement for all failure handling, real time data syncing and indexing solves all problems. when a new create happened new update then should go in ES index also postgres tables having joins, want to handle Localization too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting up elasticSearch with Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716272/setting-up-elasticsearch-with-postgresql)

Comment: Have a look at Zombodb, https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb

Comment: @Zola Found a soltuion pgsync which doing this, thanks for comment